# Mongoimport of JSON file

Tags: json, mongodb, import, mongoimport

I have a JSON file consisting of about 2000 records.  Each record which will correspond to a document in the mongo database is formatted as follows:

```
{jobID:"2597401",
account:"XXXXX",
user:"YYYYY",
pkgT:{"pgi/7.2-5":{libA:["libpgc.so"],flavor:["default"]}},     
startEpoch:"1338497979",
runTime:"1022",
execType:"user:binary",
exec:"/share/home/01482/XXXXX/appker/ranger/NPB3.3.1/NPB3.3-MPI/bin/ft.D.64",
numNodes:"4",
sha1:"5a79879235aa31b6a46e73b43879428e2a175db5",
execEpoch:1336766742,
execModify: new Date("Fri May 11 15:05:42 2012"),
startTime: new Date("Thu May 31 15:59:39 2012"),
numCores:"64",
sizeT:{bss:"1881400168",text:"239574",data:"22504"}},
```

Each record is on a single line in the JSON file, and the only line breaks are at the end of every record.  Therefore, each line in the document starts with "{jobID:"...  I am trying to import these into a mongo database using the following command:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Sat Mar  2 01:26:12 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: ,execModif
0x10059f12b 0x100562d5c 0x100562e9c 0x10025eb98 0x10000e643 0x100010b60 0x10055c4cc 0x1000014b7    
0x100001454 
 0   mongoimport                         0x000000010059f12b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongoimport                         0x0000000100562d5c _ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc + 204
 2   mongoimport                         0x0000000100562e9c _ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiRKSs + 12
 3   mongoimport                         0x000000010025eb98 _ZN5mongo8fromjsonEPKcPi + 1576
 4   mongoimport                         0x000000010000e643          
                                         _ZN6Import8parseRowEPSiRN5mongo7BSONObjERi + 2739
 5   mongoimport                         0x0000000100010b60 _ZN6Import3runEv + 7376
 6   mongoimport                         0x000000010055c4cc _ZN5mongo4Tool4mainEiPPc + 5436
 7   mongoimport                         0x00000001000014b7 main + 55
 8   mongoimport                         0x0000000100001454 start + 52
Sat Mar  2 01:26:12 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing    
    JSON string near: ,execModif
Sat Mar  2 01:26:12 
Sat Mar  2 01:26:12 imported 0 objects
Sat Mar  2 01:26:12 ERROR: encountered 1941 errors
```

I do not know what the problem is. Can someone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 422, accepted):

I was able to fix the error using the following query:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

Comment: `--jsonArray` being the ticket, yes?

Comment: Short form of this `mongoimport -d <database> -c <collection> --jsonArray -f <filename>.json`.

Comment: sometimes user/password are required `mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray -u ser -p password`

Comment: Adding to @DiegoAndrésDíazEspinoza  comment, that in my case I got an error of "unable to authenticate using mechanism 'SCRAM-SHA-1'". So, after a search, I found that it is missing the keyword `authenticationDatabase` as mentioned in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067928/6791222.

Comment: For future searchers, you might still need to install mongoimport: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/

Comment: --file fileName.json is extra and causes: "Failed: cannot decode array into a primitive.D"

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:14)` error on `--db`

Comment: + `--uri=""` for specifying the connection string for a database other than `localhost` (which is what `mongoimport` tries to use by default)

Answer (score 68):

try this,

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName <fileName.json
```

Example,

```
mongoimport --db foo --collection myCollections < /Users/file.json
connected to: *.*.*.*
Sat Mar  2 15:01:08 imported 11 objects
```

Issue is because of you date format.

I used same JSON with modified date as below and it worked

```
{jobID:"2597401",
account:"XXXXX",
user:"YYYYY",
pkgT:{"pgi/7.2-5":{libA:["libpgc.so"],flavor:["default"]}},     
startEpoch:"1338497979",
runTime:"1022",
execType:"user:binary",
exec:"/share/home/01482/XXXXX/appker/ranger/NPB3.3.1/NPB3.3-MPI/bin/ft.D.64",
numNodes:"4",
sha1:"5a79879235aa31b6a46e73b43879428e2a175db5",
execEpoch:1336766742,
execModify:{"$date" : 1343779200000},
startTime:{"$date" : 1343779200000},
numCores:"64",
sizeT:{bss:"1881400168",text:"239574",data:"22504"}}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I have the same error as in the question... Did check this import?

Comment: I adjusted the dates as you suggested and that did get rid of that particular error.  However, now I am getting a new one.  Here is the new error:

Comment: Can you paste the new JSON and which version of Mongo you are on ?

Comment: I was able to fix the error by adding --jsonArray to the end of the query.

Comment: Need to use `""` around the `.json`, if it's contain folder name has spaces in it. [Answered by Abhi below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25875547/452708)


For E.g. 
**This will not work, need to add `""` to the json file location to import it.**
`D:\>mongoimport --db testimport --collection small_zip < D:\Dev\test test\small_zips.json
The system cannot find the file specified.`

**This works**
`D:\>mongoimport --db testimport --collection small_zip < "D:\Dev\test test\small_zips.json"
2016-04-17T18:32:34.328+0800    connected to: localhost
2016-04-17T18:32:34.610+0800    imported 200 documents`

Answer (score 29):

Using **mongoimport** you can able to achieve the same

```
mongoimport --db test --collection user --drop --file ~/downloads/user.json
```

where,

```
test - Database name
user - collection name
user.json - dataset file
```

`--drop` is drop the collection if already exist.

Answer (score 22):

console:

```
mongoimport -d dbName -c collectionName dataFile.js
```

Answer (score 8):

Your syntax appears completely correct in:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json
```

Make sure you are in the correct folder or provide the full path.

Answer (score 7):

I have used below command for export DB

```
mongodump --db database_name --collection collection_name
```

and below command worked for me to import DB

```
mongorestore --db database_name path_to_bson_file
```

Answer (score 5):

### Import JSON/CSV file in MongoDB

- wait wait
- first check mongoimport.exe file in your bin folder(C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin) if it is not then download mongodb database tools(https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)
- copy extracted(unzip) files(inside unzipped bin) to bin folder(C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin)
- copy your json file to bin folder(C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin)
- Now open your commond prompt change its directory to bin

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin"
```

- Now copy this on your commnad prompt

```
mongoimport -d tymongo -c test --type json --file restaurants.json
```

- where d- database(tymongo-database name), c-collection(test-collection name)

### FOR CSV FILE

```
 mongoimport -d tymongo -c test --type csv --file database2.csv --headerline
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the import command in another terminal. (not inside mongo shell.)

```
mongoimport --db test --collection user --drop --file ~/downloads/user.json
```

Answer (score 3):

In windows you can use your Command Prompcmd  `cmd` , in Ubuntu you can use your `terminal` by typing the following command:

```
mongoimport  -d  your_database_name  -c  your_collection_name  /path_to_json_file/json_file_name.json
```

then when you open your mongo shell, you will find to check  your database_name when running this command:

```
show databases
```

Answer (score 2):

This command works where no collection is specified .

```
mongoimport --db zips "\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongodb\zips.json"
```

Mongo shell after executing the command

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
no collection specified!
using filename 'zips' as collection.
2014-09-16T13:56:07.147-0400 check 9 29353
2014-09-16T13:56:07.148-0400 imported 29353 objects
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:-**

```
mongoimport --db databaseName --collection tableName --file filepath.json
```

**Example:-**

Place your file in admin folder:-

```
C:\Users\admin\tourdb\places.json
```

Run this command on your teminal:-

```
mongoimport --db tourdb --collection places --file ~/tourdb/places.json
```

**Output:-**

```
admin@admin-PC MINGW64 /
$ mongoimport --db tourdb --collection places --file ~/tourdb/places.json
2019-08-26T14:30:09.350+0530 connected to: localhost
2019-08-26T14:30:09.447+0530 imported 10 documents
```

For more [link](http://tutorialwala.com/how-to-import-the-table-collection-json-in-mongodb/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this and it actually works:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --file D:\KKK\NNN\100YWeatherSmall.data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with me when db with usrname and password

```
mongoimport --db YOUR_DB --collection MyCollection --file /your_path/my_json_file.json -u my_user -p my_pass
```

db without username password please remove `-u my_user -p my_pass`

My sample json

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d11c815eb946a412ecd677d"), 
    "empid" : NumberInt(1), 
    "name" : "Rahul"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d11c815eb946a412ecd677e"), 
    "empid" : NumberInt(2), 
    "name" : "Rahul"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for probable answer, might help new people. In case you have multiple instances of database:

```
mongoimport --host <host_name>:<host_port> --db <database_name> --collection <collection_name>  --file <path_to_dump_file> -u <my_user> -p <my_pass>
```

Assuming credentials needed, otherwise remove this option.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just copy path of json file like example "C:\persons.json"
2. go to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
3. open cmd on that mongodb bin folder and run this command

**mongoimport --jsonArray --db dbname--collection collectionName--file FilePath**

example **mongoimport --jsonArray --db learnmongo --collection persons --file C:\persons.json**

Answer (score 1):

Number of answer have been given even though I would like to give mine command . I used to frequently. It may help to someone.

```
mongoimport original.json -d databaseName -c yourcollectionName --jsonArray --drop
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
$  mongoimport --db databaseName --collection collectionName --file filePath/jsonFile.json 


2021-01-09T11:13:57.410+0530    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2021-01-09T11:13:58.176+0530    1 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

Above I shared the query along with its response

Answer (score 1):

> **mongoimport** **-d** <*dbname*> **-c** <*collectio_name*> **--file** <*c:\users\test.json*> **--jsonArray**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. import json array data to ATLAS in your local laptop
   https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/import/mongoimport/

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.elddaddy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true" --collection Providers --drop --file /Users/Documents/data2.json --jsonArray
```

This command imports the data in the data2.json file to a collection named Providers in the MongoDB database located at the cluster0.dl79aky.mongodb.net URI.

The --drop option is used to drop the existing collection if it exists.

The --jsonArray option specifies that the input file is a JSON array, rather than a single JSON object. This allows us to import an array of documents as a batch.

The --uri option specifies the URI to connect to the database, which includes the user credentials, database name, and connection options.

Here's the breakdown of the URI:

mongodb+srv://: specifies that this is a connection string for a MongoDB Atlas cluster that uses SRV DNS record
:@: specifies the username and password of the user that is connecting to the database
cluster0.dl79aky.mongodb.net: the name of the MongoDB Atlas cluster that you want to connect to

/test: the name of the database within the cluster that you want to connect to

?retryWrites=true&w=majority: specifies the write concern options for the connection. retryWrites=true specifies that the driver should retry writes if they fail, and w=majority specifies that the write operation should wait for the majority of nodes to acknowledge the write before returning

&ssl=true: specifies that the connection should use SSL/TLS encryption

2. check your data should be json array

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "email": "john@example.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane",
    "age": 25,
    "email": "jane@example.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "bob@example.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to export this test collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5131c2bbfcb94ddb2549d501"), "field" : "Sat Mar 02 2013 13:13:31 GMT+0400"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("5131c2d8fcb94ddb2549d502"), "field" : ISODate("2012-05-31T11:59:39Z")}
```

with mongoexport (the first date created with `Date(...)` and the second one created with `new Date(...)` (if use `ISODate(...)` will be the same as in the second line)) so mongoexport output will be looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5131c2bbfcb94ddb2549d501" }, "field" : "Sat Mar 02 2013 13:13:31 GMT+0400" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5131c2d8fcb94ddb2549d502" }, "field" : { "$date" : 1338465579000 } }
```

So you should use the same notation, because strict JSON doesn't have type `Date( <date> )`.

Also your JSON is not valid: all fields name must be enclosed in double quotes, but mongoimport works fine without them.

You can find additional information in mongodb [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/import-export/#data-type-fidelity) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

Comment: I adjusted the dates as you suggested and that did get rid of that particular error.  However, now I am getting a new one.  Here is the new error:  '

Sat Mar  2 15:22:07 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: data:"1949
Sat Mar  2 15:22:07 
Sat Mar  2 15:22:07 imported 0 objects
Sat Mar  2 15:22:07 ERROR: encountered 34763 errors'

Comment: I think it's another error retaled to field `sizeT:{data: "1949..."}}`