# Create the structure of an empty collection in mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

Is there any possibility to create the structure of an empty collection in MongoDB using `mongoimport` from a JSON file like the one below?

```
"Users" : {
"name" : "string",
"telephone" : {
    "personal": { "type": "number" },
    "job": { "type" : "number" }
},
"loc" : "array",
"friends" : "object"
}
```

My goal is to create a mongoDB schema from JSON files.

Comment: MongoDB has no schema as such what is your aim by defining the schema through JSON files. I should mention this doesn't sound like a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [mongoimport a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file) and if you clear out the values of those field (set them to `""`), importing your JSON file should do just that.

However, MongoDB is a NoSQL database, and creating a schema in the MongoDB database doesn't really make sense. What will happen is that you'll have one record with fields whose values are empty.

Comment: thanks a lot Dan, I know I have to change the RDBMS "chip", but I would need to create a schema and I dont know what is the best way,  what do you advise me?

Comment: You can create the schema at the application level. For example, if you use Node.js, Mongoose supports schema definitions - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html