# Import external JSON-files to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I have a large number of JSON-files that I need to import to my Mongo database, I have also defined a schema in Mongoose, with the exact same format as my JSON-files.

Is there any way to use the terminal to import all the files to my database?

Comment: Look at the docs especially the [**mongoimport**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) command.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is straight from the docs.  

mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --file contacts.json
```

Also look at this thread as another person ran into some issues

[Mongoimport of json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file)