# Import a date(ISODate) into MongoDB using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

I have this MongoDB document. In JSON:

```
{
"attString":"hello World0",
"attInt":0,
"attDate":new Date("1990-7-20")
 }
```

How can I import this document into MongoDB using `mongoimport`? I have a problem with the *attDate* field.

This is MongoDB shell notice:

> Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #1: unexpected ISODate
> format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoimport of json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to change your date format in JSON

**Either**

```
{"attString":"hello World0","attInt":0,"attDate":ISODate("2013-11-20T23:32:18Z")}
```

**OR**

```
{"attString":"hello World0","attInt":0,"attDate":{"$date":"2013-11-20T23:32:18Z"}}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I found this because I encountered a similar error. I found that `ISODate` is supported in MongoDB 3.4, but not 2.6. `$date` is supported in both.

Comment: These solutions are not valid json... Any suggestions how to correct this?

Comment: @olefrank Does it still work if you use `"$date"` as the key, instead of just `$date`? That would make it valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, "$date" is recognized correctly from MongoDB  and is valid JSON

Comment: Is mandatory use `"$date"`, so `""` are mandatory. It is imported later how a `ISODate("same pattern used")` type