# PHP json_encoded arrays fail mongoimport

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I have a PHP script that dumps a list of people using json_decode()

```
foreach ( $personArray as $person ) {               
    $currentPosition = $person->loadCurrentPosition();
    $one[ FIELD_NAME ] = $person->getName();
    $one[ FIELD_ID ] = $person->getId();
    $one[ FIELD_ORGANIZATION_ID ] = $currentPosition->organization->getId();
    $one[ FIELD_ORGANIZATION_NAME ] = $currentPosition->organization->getName();
    $result[] = $one;
}
$jsonResult = json_encode( $result  );
```

I put the result into a file called 'people.json' :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bobby Brown",
        "id": 32632,
        "organizationid": 40492,
        "organizationname": "Exinda Networks"
    },
    {
        "name": "Billy Bob",
        "id": 32633,
        "organizationid": 29824,
        "organizationname": "Desire2Learn"
    }
]
```

I used mongoimport (mongodb v3.0.7):

```
mongoimport --db test --collection people --drop --file people.json
```

I get the following error and 0 documents imported:

```
2015-11-07T17:02:35.461-0500    Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
```

I remove the leading square bracket '[' and trailing ']' in the file and try mongoimport again:

```
2015-11-07T17:13:37.575-0500    Failed: error processing document #2: invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
```

I remove the ',' between the two JSON objects in the file and the import works:

```
2015-11-07T17:16:12.162-0500    imported 2 documents
```

Is `json_encode()` incorrectly encoding?

Will one of the `json_encode()` options result in a format that mongoimport likes?

Comment: use jsonlint.com to check the validity of your json.

Comment: thanks @aldrin27 for the PHP json_encode() file jsonlint.com says "Valid JSON". For the modified one that mongoimport read OK jsonlint.com says "Parse error" so it appears it's the mongoimport

Answer (score 1):

add "--jsonArray" option to mongoimport

big thanks to @amber4478 who answered this question [Mongoimport of json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file)