# nodejs - MongoDB crashes when having too many inserts

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Just a bit of background, MongoDB does not crash if I use `insertMany` instead.

So here's the relevant code:

```js
var propertiesObject = { results: 5000 };

request({url: "https://randomuser.me/api", qs:propertiesObject}, function(err, r, body) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
    console.log("Get response: " + r.statusCode);

    let j = JSON.parse(r.body)

    let id = 1
    let users = j.results

    for (let user of users)
    {
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function (err, db) {
            db.collection('Persons', function (err, collection) {
                collection.insert({ id, first_name: user.name.first, lastName: user.name.last })
            })
        })
        id++
    }
});
```

This causes MongoDB to crash, which requires me to run a restart of it. Is there any particular reason why it would do that? It won't crash if it's a smaller value e.g. 10

Comment: Suggestion: @A.Lau, you should try mongoimport function of MongoDB to  import bulk of data in a single shot. Here link to import list of data from JSON file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function (err, db) {
    for (let user of users){
       db.collection('persons').insert({
        id, first_name: user.name.first, lastName: user.name.last });

      id++;
    }
  })
```

Comment: ah how dumb of me, of course flooding the connections would break it.