# How can I import from db to json file to document db in mongo db?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo

I have a document db in amazon aws.I access this dbye with mongo shell.
I want to send the json file that I prepared to this document db from mylocal. How can I do that? How can I turn this mongo db out.

```
import json
import pymongo

# Making Connection
try:

    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://xxx:zzz@/sample address")
    print("Connected to MongoDB")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510049/how-to-import-json-file-to-mongodb-using-python

Comment: this is on mongodb server ie aws. i want to open this mongodb to my local

Comment: you can connect to the mongo server in aws with the url

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'

Comment: I get an error like this. I downloaded the .pem file.