# Import JSON Files from an entire directory into a MongoDB via a Python script

Tags: python, json, mongodb, automation, directory

I want to import a directory with multiple sub directories and a lot of JSON-files into a MongoDB via a python script. However I can only import multiple JSON via GUI in Compass or one file at a time using a script using the following code I gathered from another question at stackoverflow([How to import JSON file to MongoDB using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510049/how-to-import-json-file-to-mongodb-using-python)):

```
import json 
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db=client['acme']
collection_posts = db ['posts']
with open('9995-f0763044.json') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)
collection_posts.insert_one(file_data)
client.close()
```

How can I change this so I can loop through an entire directory and import all of the JSON files? I have seen the insert_many() method but as far I understood it the specific filenames still have to be written into the code. In my perfect scenario I would just enter a directory in the script and it will scan and upload all the JSON-files in that directory. Is this even possible? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob('your/path/*.json')
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_data = json.load(f)
    collection_posts.insert_one(file_data)
client.close()
```