# Import currentDate into MongoDB using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

My json looks like this:

```
{
"att1":"Hello",
"att2": "world",
"att3": //a date object with now as value
 }
```

I want to use something like $currentDate at att3 with mongoimport.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and donuts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

I suggest to create/use one file called like `common.js`And put this code in that file.

```
getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    let date = new Date()
    return { date: date, timestamp: Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) }
}
```

Now you can use above function , just import/use the `common.js` file.

As in your case, you may use it like this.

**Import common file first.**

```
 let data = {
   "att1":"Hello",
   "att2": "world",
   "att3": common.getCurrentTimeStamp().date,
   "att": common.getCurrentTimeStamp().timestamp  // FYI
 }
```

Now you have two options either you can use data or timestamp.

```
console.log("Date is ::: " , data.att3);
console.log("Timestamp is ::: " , data.att4);
```

**MongoImport command**

You may use it like this way.

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray
```

[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file)

**Update**

```
db.users.update(
 { _id: 1 },
 {
  $currentDate: {         
     "date": { $type: "timestamp" }
  }
 }
)
```

Comment: thanks you, but how you use js file with mongoimport command ?

Comment: @ElmaCherb This is alternative option.

Comment: Are you using node ? If yes i'am not. I can only use mongoimport. Maybe your solution works but i dont know how to import common.js first ! the second file contains data object, --jsonArray waits for an array ! Sorry but you have to reorganize your response. (Thank's again)

Comment: @ElmaCherb Which technology you used ?

Comment: I'am using only mongo

Comment: yes this works for update and insert, not with mongoimport command line :)