# How to import data into mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a large data file in JSON format . I'm using

`mongoimport --db verbs --collection de --file "/Users/marcelbraasch/Downloads/de.json"`

to import the data. This is going through, however, I'm getting the following exception:

> Failed: (Unauthorized) not authorized on verbs to execute command { insert: "de", ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority" }, $db: "verbs" }

I already tried combinations like this

`mongoimport -h localhost:27017 -u 'user' -p 'password' --db verbs --collection de --file "/Users/myname/Downloads/de.json"`

but none of it worked. My mongo instance is running in a docker container, if this information matters. What do I need to do?

Comment: are those username, password combination correct? do they have right permissions on verbs database? Can you run db.auth() with those credentials and cross-check?

Comment: And also hope you are not keeping the password in single quotes

Comment: And if your password has special characters you have to escape them properly on the linux bash shell.  This is a permissions error.  Either because your user does not have the proper permissions on that database and collection or because your authentication failed.

Comment: Is my second command even valid? And yeah pretty certain they are right. And no special characters. It was in single quotes. Does that matter?

Comment: I'm using `mongoimport --host="localhost" --port="27017" --username="user" --password="password" --db="verbs" --collection="de" --file="/Users/myname/Downloads/de.json"` now. This is throwing `error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.`. With the same credentials I can just log in using `mongo -u ... -p ...`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/import/). This missing keyword was `authenticationDatabase`. The command that worked for me was:

`mongoimport --db verbs --collection de --authenticationDatabase admin --username user --password password --drop --file /Users/myname/Downloads/de.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue, adding keyword --authenticationDatabase worked for me.